# Apache POI / new row in Excel with one button press

Tags: java, javafx, apache-poi

I am currently trying to write a program that can better organize your working hours. So I use Apache POI to create an Excel file. I'm already relatively far, but I can't get any further at one point. My problem is that you enter your hours per day and the program writes them in the corresponding Excel file. However, if I want to enter the next day, the program overwrites the Excel file and the previous day is deleted.
So my problem is that I don't know how to write in the rows underneath.
I've already tried FileInputStream, but it didn't really work because I create a new file every month.

This is my code for creating and writing the Excel file.

```
public void speichern(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        LocalDate localDate = date.getValue();
        datum = String.valueOf(localDate);

        do {
            if(btnNextMon.isArmed()){
                monClick++;
                System.out.println(monClick);
            }
            if (btnSave.isArmed()){
                saveClick++;
            }

            try {
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Stundenabrechnung");
                sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(18);


                Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
                data.put("1", new Object[]{"DATUM:", " INS. ABG. STUNDEN:", " ABGR. STUNDEN:", " BESCHREIBUNG:"});
                data.put("2", new Object[]{datum, ergbnis + "0", LHabg.getText(), taBes.getText()});


                Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
                int rownum = 0;
                for (String key : keyset) {
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                    Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
                    int cellnum = 0;
                    for (Object obj : objArr) {

                        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                        cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                        cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
                        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                        if (obj instanceof String) {
                            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                        } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                            cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                        }


                    }

                }
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Stundenabrechnung" + monClick +".xlsx");
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                workbook.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("ExcelFile is created succsessfully");
        }while (btnNextMon.isPressed());
}
```

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check if the file already exists before creating a new book and spreadsheet

You could use something like:

**EDIT:** I changed the line that was causing the problem

```
 try {
    boolean fileExists = new File("Stundenabrechnung" + monClick +".xlsx").exists();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        XSSFSheet sheet;
    if (fileExists) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("Stundenabrechnung" + monClick +".xlsx")));
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        
        Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
        data.put("3", new Object[]{datum, ergbnis + "0", LHabg.getText(), taBes.getText()});

        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;             
        for (String key : keyset) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {

                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                if (obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Stundenabrechnung");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(18);

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
        data.put("1", new Object[]{"DATUM:", " INS. ABG. STUNDEN:", " ABGR. STUNDEN:", " BESCHREIBUNG:"});
        data.put("2", new Object[]{datum, ergbnis + "0", LHabg.getText(), taBes.getText()});

        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {

                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                if (obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Stundenabrechnung" + monClick +".xlsx");
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the help. I understand your solution, but it still overwrites or deletes the previous day, so my excel file only got 2 rows instead of one row for each day of the month. I still dont konw whats the isssue here. So I hope you could help me out again.

Comment: Sure. It was my bad, sorry. Just change this line: int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum(); by this one: int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;  I made a rookie mistake, inexcusable.